# How to set a background image in Gluestack?

Tags: gluestack

I am using Gluestack, a mobile gaming platform that lets me play Android games on my PC2. I want to set a background image to my web page using Gluestack, but I don’t know how to do it.

What am I doing wrong? How can I set a background image to my web page using Gluestack? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

I have checked that the image file is in the same folder as the HTML file, and that the file name and extension are correct. I have also tried different image formats, like PNG and GIF, but none of them work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Published the `ImageBackground` component in gluestack today. You can refer the [docs](https://gluestack.io/ui/docs/react-native-components/image-background).

Comment: Hey Vidhi Kataria,

Just wanted to say thx m8 for your help. This was exactly what I needed to get past the block I was facing! 

Thanks again m8

Answer (score 1):

There is no component like `ImageBackground` provided by gluestack-ui. You can directly use [`ImageBackground`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/imagebackgroundcomponent) from React-Native
or
You can use `Image` component inside a `Box` and create another component and give it position `absolute`. This worked for me.

```js
import {Box, Text, VStack, Image, FocusableButton} from '@kepler-ui/themed';
import React from 'react';

export const TrendingMovie = (props: any) => {
  return (
    <Box height={900}>
      <Image size="full" source={props.imageUri} />
      <VStack space="lg" position="absolute" h="100%" justifyContent="flex-end">
        <Box w="60%" pb="$10">
          <Text fontSize="$2xl" lineHeight={'$3xl'} color="$white">
            {props.description}
          </Text>
        </Box>
        <Box pb="$10" my="$8">
          <FocusableButton title={'Watch for Free'} />
        </Box>
      </VStack>
    </Box>
  );
};
```